# How to iterate over single element of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (100, 1), having all elements similar to as shown below

```
arr[0] = array(['37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250'], dtype=object)
```

I need to iterate over this single element of array and get the last 10 elements of it. I have not been able to find out how to iterate over single element.

I tried `arr[0][-10:]` but it returned the entire element and not the last 10 elements

Comment: `arr[0][0][-10:]`

Comment: you really should probably just use a `list` here

Comment: What does "iterate over this single element of array" even mean? One usually iterates over *several* things. Can you [edit] the question to give an *example* of the full `arr`, and a sample of what iteration should cover? You might want to see the [mre] page for help.

Comment: probably you just want something like `[item[-10:] for item in arr.flat]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want by list comprehension.

```
np.array([item[0][-10:] for item in arr])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# import numpy
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250'], dtype=object)

# print the last 10 elements of the array
print(arr[0][-10:])

# iterate through the array and print the elements in reverse order
for i in arr[0][::-1]:
    print(i)

# iterate through the array and print the last 10 elements in reverse order
for i in arr[0][-10:][::-1]:
    print(I)

# iterate through the array and print the last 10 elements in forward order
for i in arr[0][-10:]:
    print(i)
```

@hpaulj makes a good point. My original answer works with numpy as requested but I didn't really leave the OP an explanation. Using his string advice this how I would do it if it was a string and I wanted to iterate for some reason:

```
s1 = '37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250'
result = 0
for x in s1[-10:]:
    print(x)
    result += int(x)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `arr.shape` is (100,1), then `arr[0].shape` is (1,), which is shown `array(['astring'])` brackets.

`arr[0,0]` should be a string, e.g. `'37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250'`

Strings take slice indexing, eg. `arr[0,0][-10:]`

`arr[0][0]` also works to get one string, but the `[0,0]` syntax is better.

It isn't clear at what level you want to `iterate`, since just getting the last 10 characters of one of the string elements doesn't need iteration.

Anyways, pay attention to what each level of indexing is producing, whether it be another array, a list, or a string.  Indexing rules for these different classes are similar, but different in important ways.